# Question about eigenvalue and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Question :

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries and $n$ eignvalues $(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},\cdots,a_{n})$, then does $det|A|=a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}\cdots a_{n}$?

(THE ANSWER IS : YES)

What I did :

$A$ is diagonalizable since it has $n$ eigenvalues, but I don't understand the "connection" between the eignvalues and the determinant, could someone explain why this the answer is yes?

Thank you!

Comment: Use definition of characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I don't understand how the definition comes in handy in this case, can you explain?

Comment: "A is diagonalizable since it has n eigenvalues". That is not true. Does it say in the question that the eigenvalues are distinct? Otherwise, your claim is false.

Comment: The question says that is has n different eigenvalues, (my bad forget to type it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You diagonalized $A$, so $A=PDP^{-1}$, then:

$$\det A=\det PDP^{-1}=\det P \cdot \det D \cdot \det P^{-1}=\det D \cdot \det P \cdot \det P^{-1} =\det D \cdot 1= \det D$$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to show that your matrix A and the corresponding diagonal matrix D have the same determinant. So the assertion follows because the determinant of D simply is $a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot .....\cdot a_n$

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand 
$$
P(\theta)=\det(
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}-\theta&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}-\theta&\ldots&a_{2n}\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}-\theta\\
\end{pmatrix}),
$$
and on other hand $$P(\theta)=(-1)^n(\theta-\theta_ 1)(\theta-\theta_2)\ldots(\theta-\theta_n).$$

Now it is left to consider free terms in above equal polynomials.